# How to add button to GDrive UI on web?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to add button to GDrive UI on web?

Does GDrive API has any APY to extend UI? (like installing application which can add button)

I want to extend Gdrive UI with button, best option for me it's to execute Google Apps Script on button click.

I also want access to select options on GDrive(to execute action on select folders/files).

I think that it can be solved by Chrome plugin that using javascript to add button and on action call Google Apps script, but it's complex way and I am not sure how to do it in right now.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, use a chrome plugin. Easy but whenever google changes something it might break. Also be wary of randomized dom properties since some google js goes through closure / caja compilation etc.

Comment: Thank you for advice.
I want to know if there is any other options available. :)